PF2e Remaster: can Trip now be used with Finesse?
Looking at the rules for maneuvers on the Athletic's skill page, Agile now applies to your Maneuvers. By the same logic present there (i.e. you are using your fists for the Trip attempt and thus get Agile), shouldn't you also inherit the Finesse trait from Fist and therefore get Finesse on the maneuver? Finesse:

You can use your Dexterity modifier instead of your Strength modifier on attack rolls using this melee weapon

While Agile states:

The multiple attack penalty you take with this weapon on the second attack on your turn is –4 instead of –5,

Shouldn't this allow me to use Finesse with Trip, Grab, etc. so long as I use a free hand to do it (as opposed to a non-Finesse unarmed attack or weapon)?

Related question about Agile

Attacks are not Attack Rolls
The rules for Attack Rolls specify that attacks only count as an attack roll when:

...you use a Strike action or make a spell attack...

whereas Maneuvers (such as Trip) are attack actions (sometimes just called attacks), which is what the rules for MAP reference:

The second time you use an attack action...

So, while the terminology is on the surface confusing, you still cannot use Finesse with Maneuvers in the Remaster.
